# Access TextBox in DataList by ID from Button-Click handler in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox which is kept inside Datalist. I need to find it via ID, so that i can insert text written to that textbox to the database.Here is my aspx page containing textbox.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ccont" Runat="Server">
  <div id="ccont">
      <asp:DataList ID="mydatalist" ItemStyle-CssClass="lft_c_down"  runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div id="wholeC">
            <div id="ctop">
             <div id="lft_l">
                <div id="lft_c_top">
                   <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ipath")%>' Height="250px" Width="300px" />
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div id="lft_c_down">
                   <b>Product Name:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"products") %>' runat="server" />
                   <br/>
                   <b>brand:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brand") %>' runat="server" />
                   <br/>
                   <b>Price:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"price") %>' runat="server" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="lft_r">
                    <b>Details:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"description") %>' runat="server" />
              </div>
           </div>
          <div id="cmt">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tb_cmt" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="620" placeholder="comment.."  />
               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Comment" backcolor="black" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Overline="False" 
                ForeColor="White" Height="34px" Width="108px" OnClick="cmt_Click" />
           </div>
         </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>

       </div>
```

The Textbox with `ID="tb_cmt"` is the text box i want to access in my code behind as:

```
protected void cmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // how to get the TextBox?
    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into comment(ecomment,sid) values(@myecomment,@mysid)", sq.con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myecomment",tb_cmt.text)//but here tb_cmt is not recognized.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`NamingContainer` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) of the button that was clicked to get the [`DataListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalistitem(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you just have to use [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the reference to your `TextBox`:

```
protected void cmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button) sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem) btn.NamingContainer;
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) item.FindControl("tb_cmt");
    //... save
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the edit.By the way can you help me with one more problem.As you can see in the above code,the comment textbox is inside the Datalist and now i want to show comments right below the commentbox.But i have to fetch data(comment) from another table.IS it possible?

Comment: Why should it be impossible to fetch data from a table? Where did you get stuck? Sorry, i don't understand the problem. You should consider to ask another question since comments are not meant to be used to answer questions ;)